# Scala Actor receive definition with Spray

Tags: scala, akka

I am using spray server, and I have a working receive implementation, which I wanted to extend, but the second one is not working:
First, working implementation:

```
def receive = runRoutes(routes)
```

Second version:

```
def receive = {
  case GetRoutes => sender() ! getRoute ~ deleteRoute ~ postRoute ~ patchRoute
  case x => runRoute(getRoute ~ deleteRoute ~ postRoute ~ patchRoute)
}
```

`runRoute` is of type `Actor.Receive`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually *call* the runRoute if you write it as you do in the 2nd example:

```
val run = runRoute(getRoute) // takes a number of implicit params to construct the route
def receive = {
  case x => run(x)
}
```

Instead of that however I'd suggest to compose the `Actor.Receive` functions using this pattern:

```
val special: Actor.Receive = { case GetRoutes => sender() ! getRoute ! ... } 
def receive: Actor.Receive = special orElse runRoute(getRoute ~ ...)
```

You can read more about chaining `PartialFunction`s on from this blog post for example: http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/02/chaining-partial-functions-with-orelse.html

Comment: Extremely helpful, clear and informational. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot